# How to get just the value from JSON.GET using RedisJSON, without the surrounding brackets and double quotes?

Tags: c, json, redis, hiredis, redisjson

Using Redis v6 and RedisJSON v2.2.0.

Sample json:

```
[
        {
                "msg": "hello",
                "sql": "blah"
        }
]
```

I can successfully get the msg value by calling:

```
redisReply *reply = redisCommand(context, "JSON.GET sample-rj $.msg");
```

It returns:

```
["hello"]
```

However I would like the redis reply to not contain the surrounding brackets and double quotes.

Is that possible to turn off on the Redis/RedisJSON side or do I have to do post processing on the string value myself?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
redisReply *reply = redisCommand(context, "JSON.GET sample-rj $.msg");

    if(reply != NULL) {

        char *trimmedStr = reply->str + 2; //remove prefix ["
        trimmedStr[strlen(trimmedStr)-2] = '\0'; //remove suffix "]

        ap_rprintf(r, "<h2>redis key val is: %s!</h2>", trimmedStr);

        freeReplyObject(reply);
    }
```

Comment: It's just because you're using the RedisJSON API directly from Hiredis, in dedicated clients in other langues the array is being parsed to a native array.